# How to remove the thousands separator in the Filedepot module?

Tags: files

I'm using the [Filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot/releases/7.x-1.x-dev) module (7.x-1.x-dev), and I have a problem with the file navigation for more than 1000 files.

I have changed the thousands separator from comma to none for parent folder, folder ID and node ID. I don't find any thousands separator option for the folder name. It works fine for filedepot/folder/1110, but not for a path like filedepot_download/1%2C235/1%2C110.

Where do I change it for filedepot_download, in the view settings?